# HighScore resets to 0

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I have been working on my xcode project for a couple of weeks now using Xcode and swift. Today when I started running the simulator my highScore was set to 0. This was the first time, it had always kept score. Does this have anything to do with the simulator or is something wrong with my code. I of course don't want the user to use my app if the highScore can reset to 0 at any given time.

```
class GameScene: SKScene {

   let labelHighScore = SKLabelNode()
   var highScore = 0

override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

   var HighscoreDefault = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
      if(HighscoreDefault.valueForKey("Highscore") != nil) {

         highScore = HighscoreDefault.valueForKey("Highscore") as! NSInteger
         labelHighScore.text = NSString(format: "%i", highScore) as String
   }

   labelHighScore.fontSize = 70
   labelHighScore.position = CGPointMake(frame.midX, frame.midY + 305)
   labelHighScore.fontColor = UIColor.blackColor()
   self.addChild(labelHighScore)
}


override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {

   if ball != blackB && ball.texture == blackB.texture {
      score += 1
      labelScore.text = String(score)

         if(score > highScore) {
            highScore = score
            labelHighScore.text = String(highScore)

            var HighscoreDefault = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
            HighscoreDefault.setValue(highScore, forKey: "Highscore")
            HighscoreDefault.synchronize()
       }
}
```

Comment: Did you use a different simulator? (ie. iPhone 6 instead of iPhone 5s?) Each device maintains its own document/preference state.

Comment: I have also noticed that every now and then the simulator could reset itself for no reason and this will wipe out your settings.

Comment: I think it's pretty safe to assume that when you publish the app you will not have this issue. Although the simulator is pretty accurate to the behavior of a real iPhone, it is not 100%.

Comment: You have a lot of simple mistakes in your code that could be the reason that your code isn't working:
 
 
 first of all, you should close your open parenthesis on this last line `HighscoreDefault.synchronize(`
 
 
 
 
 In code, punctuation and grammar are as, if not **MORE** important than the actual code. I have had an entire web page break because I was missing a space somewhere...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless your using the same device it would not keep the same user defaults. If you have always used the simulator they are known to reset from time to time. My suggestions would be to explicitly set the high score's default and run. comment out the code that sets the default and re run. It should maintain that value.